# Openvpn TLS handshake error only on linux clients

Tags: openvpn

I configured my VPN to accept traffic on udp 1194 on the server.

I generated 3 .ovpn files including keys and certifications. 
I tested the 3 configuration files on Windows Openvpn client and also on Android Openvpn connect without any problem.

Now I'm trying to make it working on a Debian system but I cannot figure out why it's not working. The client is under the same network of the Windows pc so I think the firewall can't block it.

The debian client just timeout during TLS authentication reporting : TLS key negotiation failed... and TLS handshake failed.

On the server side I can see a packet coming " TLS: Initial packet from .." then also here we have a

> TLS error after 60 seconds: TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed.

What can I do?

Comment: Do a packet trace and check why this machine is loosing/blocking packets.

Answer (score 1):

I've tunneled the 1194 port via SSH and the client was able to connect so I think that the LAN is firewalled on the linux machine and not on the windows one.. maybe the Admin grant me special rights on the Windows pc.